# What are the steps involving in hg clone?(Description Inside)

Tags: c#, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm learning the mercurial source code management system and doing the examples using [hgsharp](http://live.hglabhq.com/projects/hgsharp/repositories/hgsharp/source/files/a0c136f62784).

In that I studied the [hg clone](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TutorialClone) ,

[image]

done in command prompt as per the tutorial instruction (see the above screenshot), but can't understand how the files are creating while cloning process is in progress. I tried using [hgsharp](http://live.hglabhq.com/projects/hgsharp/repositories/hgsharp/source/files/a0c136f62784) as they coded in the HgCloneTest, but only the .hg folder is created, other files are not created.

Could somebody say me how the files are created while cloning a repo.

Comment: When you cloned via cmd prompt ( specifically the clone you screenshotted ), do you still only end up with a repo with just the .hg folder ( from the output displayed this shouldn't be the case ). I'm not familiar with hgsharp, but it is possible that when it clones for you you, you might only get the .hg folder, as that is an option when cloning.

Comment: @Kindread I need to clone the entire repo including the .hg folder. can you say me what is that option.

Comment: by default, if you just use 'hg clone <repo>', it will create the clone and all the files in the repo. But If you say 'hg clone <repo> -U', then it will only create the .hg folder, which I suspect is what hgsharp is doing. However in the screenshot you gave for your clone via cmd prompt, it looks like it should have created everything, which is why I'm asking if that particular clone is only showing the .hg folder.

Comment: oh, and I forgot to mention, if a repo only has the .hg folder, you can 'solve' the issue by doing a 'hg update -C' on that repo. But I'd still like to help you understand why its not doing what you expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at last I understood the concept. While cloning a particular repo if we say --no update, then the working directory will not get updated. Thanks to @Kindread.

Also, That HgSharp is cloning the repo by not updating the working directory and does not cover 100% functionality.

Comment: This fork, https://bitbucket.org/hindlemail/hgsharp , has more clone functionality implemented.

Comment: @Tom "Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.File.Move" in HgFileSystem, Is this working working for you.

Comment: It throws me an exception for me, "A call to PInvoke function 'AlphaFS!Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.NativeMethods::MoveFileWithProgressW' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature."

Comment: I haven't seen that exception. My dev box is a 64bit Windows machine. Are you using a 32bit Windows OS?

Comment: @Tom Me too using 64 bit windows 8.